# magento and paypal integration

Tags: magento, paypal

I'm trying to integrate PayPal into my Magento 1.6 store, preferably the `Website Payments Standard`

I have followed all the steps to add this to my payment page, but when I get to the payment page, the radio button is missing, so I cannot select it.

It seems that the radio is `display:none` in the HTML source.

Has anyone ever come across this before?

Thanks

Comment: You didn't forget to enable the module, or to enable the payment method, or to refresh all active caches, by chance?

Comment: The module is enabled under `System -> Config -> Advanced -> Mage_PaypalUk`. I am trying to use this from a UK PayPal account. Where is the setting to enable the payment method? Like i said it displays, just with no radio button. Cache is off, but has been refreshed several times

Comment: Sorry, misread. I thought it isn't shown at all in the checkout. To answer your other question: `System -> Config -> Sales -> Payment Methods -> PayPal -> Enabled`.

Comment: No the PayPal logo and the link is shown, but the radio button isn't displayed. Is it because it is the only payment option available?

Comment: Why use Website Payments Standard when you can use Express Checkout? They're both free, globally available (definitely in the UK), while Express Checkout is a much more elegant (and secure!) product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have only one payment method enabled, no radio button will be shown. The customer doesn't have to need to choose when he/she have only one option.